# Removed SD Card while it was formatting and it's not recognized anymore

Tags: partitioning, formatting, sd-card

I have this SD Card which I connect to my PC with a USB Reader. I was formatting the card but it was taking too long and I had other more important things to do so I just unplugged the card. Now it's not recognized.

The card reader is working fine other cards but not with this one. The partition is not recognized at all. Is the card completetly broken and I might as well throw it out or is there any way to make it work again?

Information from `diskpart`:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          476 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          238 GB  1024 KB        *
* Disk 2    No Media           0 B      0 B

DISKPART> clean

Virtual Disk Service error:
There is no media in the device.
```

Computer Management - Disk Management:

[image]

Comment: Why not simply try to reformat the card? If you have windows, you can try using diskpart - and find the option for "Clean" and see how you go. WARNING: diskpart is powerful and can cause damage if used improperly (or accidentally using this tool against the wrong disk / partition / volume)

Comment: Formatting through Windows (not diskpart) doesn't work because the drive/partition is not even recognized. Didn't try diskpart yet.

Comment: You can also try using Computer Management - Disk Management. If the SD card is recognized (at all) - it should be listed there. The partition may be messed up - but you should be able to remove any partition / Volume from there.

Comment: Tried that already before posting this. The drive is recognized, the partition is not and I can't do anything with the partition, will edit original post with more info.

Comment: You'll need software to low-level format the card. These are often available from the card's manufacturer. There's also a [generic one](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) available.

Comment: It says no media, so it appears it is only seeing your flash card reader but not the card at all. This seems normal to me if the card has gone completely bad.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Doesn't work because this card does not appear in the dropdown.

Comment: I guess @Appleoddity is right, it has gone completely bad.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral It would seem so then. :(

Answer (score 1):

If it errors during a write operation, then the firmware protect would kick in & make the card read-only.

This is to all intents & purposes irreversible.

Bin it & get a new one.